# incompatible types, expected hashmap found String

Tags: java

```
public class Readparam
{
    private static String method_name;
    public static HashMap<String, Vector<String>> getParameters(String file_name)
    {
        HashMap temp_map = new HashMap();

        String current_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        File new_file = new File(current_dir + "\\parameters\\" + file_name);

        StringTokenizer stringtok = null;
        StringBuffer temp_contents = new StringBuffer();

        BufferedReader input = null;
        try
        {
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new_file));
            String current_line = null;

            while (((current_line = input.readLine()) != null) && (current_line.length() > 0))
            {
                stringtok = new StringTokenizer(current_line, "(");

                method_name = stringtok.nextToken();

                String parsed_parameters = current_line.subSequence(current_line.indexOf("(") + 1, current_line.indexOf(")")).toString();

                StringTokenizer paramtok = new StringTokenizer(parsed_parameters, ",");

                String[] parsed_string = parsed_parameters.split(", ");
                String parsing = method_name + "(";

                for (int i = 0; i < parsed_string.length; i++)
                {
                    String[] temp_parse = parsed_string[i].split(" ");
                    if (i < parsed_string.length - 1)
                    parsing = parsing + temp_parse[0] + ", ";
                else {
                parsing = parsing + temp_parse[0];
                }
            }
                parsing = parsing + ")";

                Vector temp_vector = new Vector();
                for (String s : parsed_string) {
                temp_vector.add(s);
            }
                temp_map.put(parsing, temp_vector);
        }
    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + file_name);
        String method_name = null;
        return method_name;
    }
```

any help on this is aprreciated
I have the last line "return method_name that does not compile
i recieve an error incompatible types, expected java.util.hashmap found java.lang.String
the last line return method_name does not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("File not found: " + file_name);
HashMap<String, Vector<String>> method_name = null;
return method_name;
```

Since your method is of a certain type, you need to 'cast' the value that's being returned to that type.

If you are coding using Eclipse, you can just click on the little error icon, and it will offer to fix the error for you, and it will cast it for you.  If you are not using Eclipse, you might consider it in the future.  (NetBeans works in a similar manner)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is declared to return `HashMap<String, Vector<String>>` (which is odd to start with - usually you'd use `List` rather than `Vector` if you're using the Java 2 collections). But then your only return statement is here:

```
String method_name = null;
return method_name;
```

That's clearly not returning a `HashMap<String, Vector<String>>`, is it? What do you expect that to do? You *could* just write

```
return null;
```

which would return a null reference as a `HashMap<String, Vector<String>>`. (Personally I'd just let the exception bubble up, but that's a different matter.)

(It also doesn't help that you haven't shown the end of your method, and that some of the indentation is decidedly odd.)